# Setting javascript object number to x and y values

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert a number to object

I have a javascript object that looks like this

```
settings = {
    offset: 20
}
```

to

```
settings.offset: {
    x: 20,
    y: 20
}
```

I thought it would have been as easy as doing

```
if (typeof settings.offset == 'number') {
    var tValue = settings.offset;
    settings.offset['x'] = tValue;
    settings.offset['y'] = tValue;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? FYI: that is not JSON...

Comment: And that's an object not an array. You should go back and look at your JS terminology again.

Comment: That isn't working, if I try to use `settings.offset['x']` i get undefined.

Comment: Because it is a number.

Comment: try set offset to a new object before assign x and y values. `settings.offset = {}`

Comment: Thank you for correcting my terminology. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set properties on a number. Change it to an object.

```
if (typeof settings.offset == 'number') {
    var tValue = settings.offset;
    settings.offset = {};
    settings.offset['x'] = tValue;
    settings.offset['y'] = tValue;
}
```

or

```
if (typeof settings.offset == 'number') {
    var tValue = settings.offset;
    settings.offset = {
        'x' : tValue,
        'y' : tValue
    };
}
```

Comment: This worked. I can't mark this as the answer for another 8 minutes.